# ("WScript.Network").UserName in not being Saved in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I used the following VBA Code in The Form (General)

```
Public Function GetUserName() As String
    GetUserName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
End Function
```

The Control source = User_Name
Default Value = GetUserName()

The Problem - 
The username is correctly Pulled in the form, however it is not being saved in the Control Source i.e in the Table. Even after I save and close the form.

I need the form to capture and save the Username every time someone makes changes to a record.

Please Help I am new to MS Access

Comment: There's an `Environ$` function you can use to get the Windows login username, does `Environ$("USERNAME")` not return the correct value? In any case, that's just a function that gets a string, it's not saving anything anywhere. Who's calling that code? Please [edit] your post to include the code that's relevant to the problem.

Comment: The code is relevant to the problem.  According to many user comments Environ("USERNAME") is easily spoofed and hence the approach to use   WScript.Network object. is used. The issue is that I am not able to capture it in the table every time some one logs in.

Comment: lol, this is VBA. Ctrl+Break and anyone can spoof anything.

Comment: I tested to your code and it works. However, DefaultValue only executes on new record creation, not on record edits. If you want to change the value then will need code to do that.

Comment: I use the following code  so the form opens at a new record DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec   - Still it does not save the value. I kind of understand what you are saving. Let me explain me a a bit clearly - On opening the application the application opens at  welcome Log in page which pulls the Default time, Date and User name to Track who opens and edits the Application

Comment: I cannot replicate issue. As soon as I initiate a new record by data entry to any field, the User_Name field receives value via the function. When record is committed to table, the User_Name field has data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are assigning the user name to the control source. Access does not work like this. The control source is supposed to contain a column name.

Create a table having columns you can use to store things. Then set the form's [Record Source property](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/formbasics2010/basics04.php) to this table name at design time in the properties window. Then set the `Control Source` of a text box to the column name where you want to store data or [add objects to the form](https://www.techonthenet.com/access/tutorials/formbasics2010/basics09.php) using the fields list.

Iin the form load event you can assign a user name to this textbox with

```
me!theTextBoxName = GetUserName()
```

You can also do this with an unbound textbox, but this name will not be stored when you close the form.

---

But as @June7 points out, you have probably done this already. In this case you should open the form with

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "theFormName", DataMode:=acFormAdd
```

... to create a new record.

Comment: I think OP has already done that. The question shows that the ControlSource is bound to field named User_Name.

Comment: Yes I am using Existing Table Field  User_Name to store the values. I will try the Form load Method to see if it can store. Thank you

Comment: in the form load event, assigning a user name to this textbox with

me!theTextBoxName = GetUserName()      -  Worked well instead of Assigning it to default value. Thank you Everyone